# What's the eloquent way to use the run date for a weekly Airflow job?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

**The problem**: Airflow's `execution_date` is defined as the beginning of the period between runs. For example, a DAG run on a weekly schedule would run on *2018-01-08 T11:00:00*, but the `execution_date` would be *2018-01-01 T11:01:00*.

**The objective**: I receive a file once a week, with the file date in the file's name. To identify the file, I'd like to use Airflow's `execution_date`. But I cannot seem to find a way to use the date of the run, versus using the earliest possible `execution_date` for a period.

**Possible solutions**:

- Modify the `execution_date` on the fly. Something like: `context['execution_date'] + timedelta(days=7)`. This seems hacky.
- Run the DAG daily, insert a `ShortCircuitOperator` at the beginning of the DAG execution graph, exit if `execution_date` is not the expected date.

All suggestions or recommendations are welcomed. It's a nuanced problem, but causing some issues with my ETL pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution?

- Have the DAG run once a week just after you "think" the file will arrive. Parse the names of the files in the landing area which will give you a bunch of dates. Check and see which of these dates is between the execution_date + schedule_interval (or next_execution_date if you're using airflow version >= 1.8). Then ingest file/s which match.

I think using execution_date + timedelta(days=7) is a bit hacky, intead use the execution_date + schedule_interval, that way if the interval changes there shouldn't be any issues (I do this for one of my DAGS). If you're using a newer airflow version then you can use the next_execution_date which is better.

Comment: this is great. `next_execution_date` is nice. doesn't handle external triggers properly though :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm using macro for this issue.

This function (for macro) can handle manual trigger, too.

```py
def weekly_today(execution_date, run_id, years=0, months=0, days=0, fmt="%Y%m%d"):
    d = pendulum.instance(execution_date)
    if run_id.startswith('scheduled_'):
        d = d.add(days=7)
    return d.add(years=years, months=months, days=days).strftime(fmt)
```

This function should be added to DAG as `user_defined_macros`

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test',
    start_date=timezone.datetime(2019, 6, 24, 6),
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=7),
    user_defined_macros={
        'weekly_today': weekly_today
    },
)
```

And I needed to set data range from 1 year ago to today.
Here is sample macro usage.

```
from_macro = '{{ weekly_today(execution_date, run_id, years=-1) }}'
to_macro = '{{ weekly_today(execution_date, run_id) }}'
```

bad naming.. but works.